# "then come six o’clock he’ll roll on in. Been to the zoo."

Tags: phrase-meaning

Would you please explain the meaning of the *italic* part of the sentence below?
Are there any words omitted?

> **Callie**
> Looks like it. I can’t be doing with this. The amount of
> paperwork I’ve got…You know what’ll happen. We’ll spend all day,
> running around in circles and *then come six o’clock he’ll roll on in.*
> *Been to the zoo.*
> https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/english/course/fatherandson/unit-1/session-2/activity-5

My guess is that someone will come at six o'clock and things will be messed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's three parts to your question.

1. "*come six o'clock*" roughly means "when six o'clock comes". This structure can be used to talk about various things that arrive in an abstract way:

> "Come fall, we'll be able to harvest these pumpkins."
> "My son's coming 18 and off to university."
> "Come graduation, I'm moving away."

It cannot be used for physical things, like:

> *"Come the asteroid, ..."
> *"Come the taxi, ..."

2. "*rolls on in*" is the phrasal verb "rolls in", with "on" inserted, which sounds more casual, friendly or "folksy". With many phrasal verbs, it's possible to add "on" between the verb and the particle:

> "Come on in whenever you're ready."
> "I'm gonna head on out after this drink."
> "The red team is really moving on up the leader board."

It's not possible to insert "on" in phrasal verbs with "on" or "off" as the particle:

> "*Put this jacket on on"
> "*I told him on off"

Speakers of some US dialects nearly always insert "on", regardless of context.

3. Here, "*Been to the zoo*" means, "I've been to the zoo". This is a quote of what "he" will say when he arrives at six o'clock. For stylistic reasons, the writer chose not the put quotation marks around this sentence.

Comment: Your answer gave me an inspiration!

"When six o'clock comes, he (the missing person) will come back.
And he will say 'I've been to the zoo.'"

Comment: Can I ask where you are from?  "My son's coming 18" sounds very odd to me, although "Come the fall" or "Come graduation" are fine.  I am a New York City native.

Comment: @stangdon It's not entirely natural to me either (a Canadian), but it's referenced that way at [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come). More natural to me would be "My son's coming **(up) on** 18", but that's not the usage the OP is asking about

Comment: "cometh the hour, cometh the man".

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of colloquial expressions:

1. *Come six o'clock* is a colloquial way of saying *at six o'clock*. It's particularly common in telling a story.
2. *He'll roll on in* means *he'll arrive*, with an implication of him being careless or vague. It might mean that he'll be drunk, but it doesn't necessarily mean that.

Typically British, I think: I'm pretty sure the first one is not used in American English.